# Solve $f^{''}(t) + 7f^{'}(t) + 6f(t) = e^{-3t}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $f^{''}(t) + 7f^{'}(t) + 6f(t) = e^{-3t}$

I figured out that the solution of $f^{''}(t) + 7f^{'}(t) + 6f(t) = 0$ is $c_1e^{-6t} + c_2e^{-t}$, so I just have to add one solution to the kernel.. but not sure how I find that one solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions to
$$
f''+7f'+6f=0
$$
are $C_1e^{-6t}+C_2e^{-t}$. A particular solution to
$$
f''+7f'+6f=e^{-3t}
$$
can often be gotten by seeing what the operator does to $e^{-3t}$:
$$
9e^{-3t}-21e^{-3t}+6e^{-3t}=-6e^{-3t}
$$
Due to the linearity of the operator, we get that
$$
f=-\frac16e^{-3t}
$$
is a particular solution.

Answer (score 2):

Guess something like $y_p=ke^{-3t}$. Then $9ke^{-3t}-21ke^{-3t}+6ke^{-3t}=e^{-3t}$

Solve for $k$ and then your total solution is the homogenous which you found plus this particular solution